# How to reset other core of ARM Cortex A9?

Tags: arm, boot, zynq

I want to reset the other cores of a **Cortex A9 CPU** in the primary CPU, but I can't find the instructions of how to reset it.

I am using *Xilinx Device Zynq*, the board is *ZedBoard*.
I want to run a muti-core realtime OS on it, but I can't do a software reset on it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about all arm cores but I think the resets are around the edge of the core so you would need to ask your fpga designer or xilinx, etc.  it may or may not be a register depending on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Zynq [Datasheet](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview.pdf) says it has Cortex-A9 MPCore. [MPCore TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0407i/DDI0407I_cortex_a9_mpcore_r4p1_trm.pdf) has some sections e.g. 5.2.4. Individual processor software reset, but the text just gives HW reset sequence.

It would seem that ARM discourages the software reset that you are asking for. But you could also check [Cortex-A9 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0388i/index.html).

Comment: yeah, I got it ,thanks a lot, I have refer to this reference and I have find a method when reading xilinx zynq fsbl source code